# mahout seqdirectory fails to read input file

Tags: mapreduce, mahout

I ran Mahout with `seqdirectory` but it failed and said the input file doesn't exist. Indeed the file exits.

```
$ ls train-data/ -l
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 hadoop hadoop 5761396717 Feb 25 09:28 enwiki-20100904-pages-articles1.xml



$ mahout seqdirectory -i train-data/enwiki-20100904-pages-articles1.xml -o train-data
Running on hadoop, using /home/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
MAHOUT-JOB: /home/hadoop/mahout-distribution-0.9/examples/target/mahout-examples-0.9-job.jar
14/03/31 19:45:05 INFO common.AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--charset=[UTF-8], --chunkSize=[64], --endPhase=[2147483647], --fileFilterClass=[org.apache.mahout.text.PrefixAdditionFilter], --input=[train-data/enwiki-20100904-pages-articles1.xml], --keyPrefix=[], --method=[mapreduce], --output=[train-data], --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[temp]}
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: train-data/enwiki-20100904-pages-articles1.xml
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:558)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory.runMapReduce(SequenceFilesFromDirectory.java)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory.run(SequenceFilesFromDirectory.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory.main(SequenceFilesFromDirectory.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
    at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileSystem which you are refering is LocalFileSystem but the operation is expecting the files in HDFS. So, either move the files in HDFS or set MAHOUT_LOCAL variable.