# hadoop "Can not create a Path from an empty string"

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I am a beginner of hadoop.
I have been getting error as following.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.stringToPath(StringUtils.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:499)
        at org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory.runMapReduce(SequenceFilesFromDirectory.java:172)
        at org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory.run(SequenceFilesFromDirectory.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
        at org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory.main(SequenceFilesFromDirectory.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:152)
        at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

The code is here.

```
"username"@lena:~/Coursework$ mahout seqdirectory -i docs -o docs-seqfiles -c UTF-8 -chunk 5
```

There are some similar questions I found, but nothing worked in my case.
I hope somebody could find a solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your files are in Local File System, 2 things should help out:

- Put folder/files on HDFS and set -i [HDFS path] -o [HDFS path]
- set MAHOUT_LOCAL

refer: [mahout seqdirectory fails to read input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765468/mahout-seqdirectory-fails-to-read-input-file)

Comment: hi, sorry for asking but do you mind explaining how to find the HDFS path?

Comment: haha. Sorry that I dont even remember anything since I'm no longer work on Hadoop! I'm sure You will figure out cuz this is a common task.